# iOS 10: Can't install enterprise distribution build from site/url

Tags: ios, ios10, enterprise-distribution

I can't be able to install app from url in iOS 10 being specific in iOS 10.0.2 I have tried to install in iOS < 10 and I was able to install it, **but not in iOS 10.0.2**, it is giving popup "Would you like to install app "x"?" Once, we click Install it does nothing. We are using enterprise distribution. The app that i'm installing in an update for an app that already exists on my users devices.

Device: iPhone 6 plus, Version: 10.0.2

Request you to help, thanks

Comment: I am also getting the same issue.did you got solution?

Comment: Restoring the iOS device always solves the issue, another way without restoring is changing the bundle identifier in your server `.plist`, delete cache ans reinstall certificate, but it seems that is not working in all the devices.